# Copy New Entries to Another Sheet without duplicates

Tags: google-appsheet

I have 2 sheets named [source (appsheet included)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xTRfU1qvHjAiKAAc3d7sUkcZHbB5-uORvnn-1JvCzhI/edit#gid=0) and [target](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s6B6OURQ7FFmP106mrE9laqZ3XLwiXtjway6iGyWsOk/edit#gid=0). If column "Finalized" is yes, I want that row to be copied into target. However, I do not want duplicate data.

Here is my attempt below. Not too sure what I am doing wrong. [Entire pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/gQMwdwSQ). Thanks in advance.

```
function moveRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1s6B6OURQ7FFmP106mrE9laqZ3XLwiXtjway6iGyWsOk').getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  const targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();  
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  let sortRange = sheet.getSheetValues(2,1,lastRow, 4); 
  let targetCounter = 1;  

  Logger.log(lastRow)
 
  for (var i = 1; i <= sortRange.length; i++) {
    let finalized = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue(); 
    console.log(i + " - " + finalized);
 
    let duplicateCheck = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetLastRow, 4).getValues();
    let isDuplicate = false;
 
    for (var j = 0; j < duplicateCheck.length; j++) {
    if (JSON.stringify(duplicateCheck[j]) === JSON.stringify(sortRange[i - 1])) {
      isDuplicate = true;
      break;
      }
    }
 
      if (!isDuplicate && finalized == "Yes") {
        let rowValues = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
        targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow+targetCounter, 1, 1, 4).setValues(rowValues); 
        targetCounter++; 
      }
  }; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  ui.createMenu(' Automation Tools')
    .addItem('Move "Yes" to another sheet', 'moveRows')
    .addToUi(); 
}; 
 
function moveRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ENTER_GOOGLE_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let sortRange = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, lastRow, 4);
 
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  let targetCounter = 1;
 
  for (var i = 1; i <= sortRange.length; i++) {
    let name = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    let id = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue(); // Assuming ID is in column 2
    console.log(i + " - " + name);
 
    if (name == "Yes") {
      // Check if the row already exists in the target sheet based on the unique ID
      let rowExists = false;
      for (let j = 2; j <= targetLastRow + targetCounter; j++) {
        let targetID = targetSheet.getRange(j, 2).getValue();
        if (id === targetID) {
          rowExists = true;
          break;
        }
      }
 
      if (!rowExists) {
        let rowValues = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
        targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + targetCounter, 1, 1, 4).setValues(rowValues);
        targetCounter++;
      } else {
        console.log("Duplicate row found and skipped.");
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**